# Protobuf without a proto file

Tags: java, serialization, protocol-buffers

I want to do RPC on Java using ProtoBuf, but without the development overhead of defining metadata for each class. Java serialization and Kryo can do this. Is it possible with ProtoBuf?

I appreciate that the metadata in a `.proto` file gives benefits like versioning, but for RPC between systems that I control and that are launched together that is less relevant -- compare the way that Apache Spark uses Kryo.

Comment: If you're choosing RPC framework, you might be interested in [gRPC](http://www.grpc.io/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible. Note that you write only proto file, class is generated for you by `protoc` compiler. So I would say that the only overhead is to integrate `protoc` into your build system (AFAIK there are Maven and Gradle plugins).

Comment: The overhead is that you need to trace the exact state to store from each class, including the closure of the reference graph. With Java Serialization or Kryo, you don't need to do that.